Power BI make Measure static Value and dynamic
I have the following data
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TBL') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TBL
create table #TBL (category varchar(6), Year_Vs_Year VARCHAR(20),   Cost INT)
INSERT INTO #TBL VALUES
(null,'24/25 vs 19/20',7),(null,'24/25 vs 20/21',208),(null,'24/25 vs 21/22',98),
(null,'24/25 vs 22/23',28),(null,'24/25 vs 23/24',67),(null,'24/25 vs 24/25',28),
('AE','24/25 vs 19/20',881959),('AE','24/25 vs 20/21',1424903),('AE','24/25 vs 21/22',3052440),
('AE','24/25 vs 22/23',1975536),('AE','24/25 vs 23/24',1524131),('AE','24/25 vs 24/25',956217),
('DP','24/25 vs 19/20',133),('DP','24/25 vs 20/21',6),('DP','24/25 vs 21/22',20),
('DP','24/25 vs 22/23',6),('DP','24/25 vs 23/24',17),('DY','24/25 vs 19/20',66587),
('DY','24/25 vs 20/21',53731),('DY','24/25 vs 21/22',55157),('DY','24/25 vs 22/23',68488),
('DY','24/25 vs 23/24',75492),('DY','24/25 vs 24/25',46234),('EV','24/25 vs 19/20',93),
('EV','24/25 vs 20/21',50),('EV','24/25 vs 21/22',342),('EV','24/25 vs 23/24',714),('EV','24/25 vs 24/25',64),
('GP','24/25 vs 19/20',3513842),('GP','24/25 vs 20/21',2499217),('GP','24/25 vs 21/22',3266166),
('GP','24/25 vs 22/23',3517609),('GP','24/25 vs 23/24',4133396),('GP','24/25 vs 24/25',2804384),
('IP','24/25 vs 19/20',2258417),('IP','24/25 vs 20/21',2622805),
('IP','24/25 vs 21/22',3613080),('IP','24/25 vs 22/23',2905209),('IP','24/25 vs 23/24',2632569),('IP','24/25 vs 24/25',1768455),
('OH','24/25 vs 19/20',42040),('OH','24/25 vs 20/21',73167),('OH','24/25 vs 21/22',81570),('OH','24/25 vs 22/23',27576),
('OH','24/25 vs 23/24',23651),('OH','24/25 vs 24/25',14776),('OP','24/25 vs 19/20',2185227),('OP','24/25 vs 20/21',1973621),
('OP','24/25 vs 21/22',3078435),('OP','24/25 vs 22/23',2795034),('OP','24/25 vs 23/24',2735693),('OP','24/25 vs 24/25',1791504),
('PP','24/25 vs 19/20',74566),('PP','24/25 vs 20/21',27627),('PP','24/25 vs 21/22',22976),('PP','24/25 vs 22/23',12624),
('PP','24/25 vs 23/24',11224),('PP','24/25 vs 24/25',2928),('QC','24/25 vs 19/20',42588),('QC','24/25 vs 20/21',44024),
('QC','24/25 vs 21/22',64487),('QC','24/25 vs 22/23',69394),('QC','24/25 vs 23/24',84978),('QC','24/25 vs 24/25',48377),
('RE','24/25 vs 19/20',32),('RE','24/25 vs 20/21',44),('UN','24/25 vs 19/20',46788),('UN','24/25 vs 20/21',302300),
('UN','24/25 vs 21/22',368105),('UN','24/25 vs 22/23',116676),('UN','24/25 vs 23/24',58059),('UN','24/25 vs 24/25',42589)
select * from #TBL

Currently the data is like this

in power bi i wrote the code bellow
Cost without current year = 
var a = MAX(Pathology[fiscal_year])
var b =CALCULATE(([Cost]),a= Pathology[fiscal_year])
var c = CALCULATE(SUM(Pathology[Cost]),ALL('Pathology'))
RETURN
c

It is given funny result

Expected output should be the value of the max year

All the values should max year value as displayed  above
Thanks


Based on the data you shared, shouldn't the result for AE be 3,052,440 instead of 956,217?

@AgustinPalacios the data shoud only show the Last Data (Max year) for all

This Dax measure produce the expected result:
Max Cost without Year = 
VAR __maxYear = CALCULATE( MAX( Pathology[fiscal_year]), ALL(Pathology ) )
VAR __result = CALCULATE( MAX( Pathology[Cost] ), Pathology[fiscal_year] = __maxYear )
VAR __subtable = 
    FILTER( 
        ALL( Pathology ), 
    Pathology[fiscal_year] = __maxYear 
)
VAR __sum = 
    SUMMARIZE( 
    __subtable, 
    Pathology[Category],  
        "@MaxCost", SUM( Pathology[Cost] ) 
    )

RETURN 
    IF( 
       HASONEVALUE( Pathology[Category]), 
       __result, 
       SUMX( __sum, [@MaxCost] ) 
    )


